# Campos Duplicados en Php y Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Me pueden ayudar, tengo código donde me busca en la tabla los "**Nombre de Equipo Duplicados**" pero con serial y usuario diferente; pero me gustaría que allí mismo me busque los que están con el mismo "**Nombre de Equipo Repetido**" y mismo usuario repetido para ese "Nombre de Equipo".
_
Con este codigo Obtengo unos repetidos, pero me faltaría que tengan el mismo user

```
SELECT e1.Equipo, e1.Serial, e1.User FROM epo e1 JOIN ( SELECT Equipo FROM epo GROUP BY Equipo HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Serial) > 1 AND COUNT(User) > 1 ) e2 ON e1.Equipo = e2.Equipo;
```

Comment: me gustaria tener o ver la estructura de la tablas mas que el query...

Comment: Estos son los campos que se generan.
      1 Equipo varchar(200) 
 2 EPOCloud varchar(200) 
 3 User varchar(200) 
 4 IP varchar(200) 
 5 Serial varchar(200) 
 6 FechaReporte date   
 7 Managed State varchar(200)

Answer (score 0):

Para una tabla como esta:

```
CREATE TABLE `epo` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Equipo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Serial` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`User` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `epo` (`id`, `Equipo`, `Serial`, `User`) VALUES
(1, 'Cómputo', '123', 'Luis'),
(2, 'Sonido', '456', 'Pedro'),
(3, 'Cómputo', '789', 'Luis'),
(4, 'Luminaria', '123', 'Victor'),
(5, 'Sonido', '456', 'Luis'),
(6, 'Sonido', '234', 'Ana'),
(7, 'Luminaria', '789', 'Ana'),
(8, 'Cómputo', '678', 'Victor'),
(9, 'Sonido', '345', 'Pedro'),
(10, 'Luminaria', '234', 'Luis');
```

Bastaría con usar la sentencia `GROUP BY` pasándole los campos **Eqipos** y **User**, y luego con `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` se le indica que los campos deben estar presentes mas de una vez:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS cantidad_duplicados
FROM epo
GROUP BY Equipo, User
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

El resultado sería algo así:

| id | Equipo | Serial | User | cantidad_repeticiones |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cómputo | 123 | Luis | 2 |
| 2 | Sonido | 456 | Pedro | 2 |

Comment: Gracias. Pero con ese código que me pasaste no me filtra los demás, que quiero decir, que si lo hago con ese sql solo me va a traer aquellos que tienen el mismo nombre y mismo serial. En cambio con el que arme me trae todo aquel que tiene mismo nombre y diferente serial, pero solo me falta que también me traiga lo que primero menciono.